# Flask + gunicorn + meinheld stucks serving static content

Tags: python, templates, flask, gunicorn

I have a Python API made in Flask, it only has a small frontend view that is a single template and several js, css and some png.
Everything is included in a Docker container. In debug (without being inside the container of Docker) everything works correctly, but inside the container, when entering to serve this page "Home" (Path "/") there are certain elements that take exaggeratedly in being served by the Flask, when I say exaggeratedly I mean even to 4 or 5 minutes, is as they were stuck.

Also, this makes Gunicorn workers take 100% CPU.

The stack in the container is meinheld + gunicorn + Flask. The configuration of the static content could not be simpler, the template is in the folder "/templates" and the static content in "/static", within the template I use:

```
<link href="{{url_for('static',filename='bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I can't find the key of what the hell is going on with certain elements, which take an eternity to load and also, the gunicorn workers collapse. Any ideas?

Thanks.